# Launching additional Powershell instance with commands from a text file

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a Powershell script that takes in a text file as a parameter. The text file looks similar to this:

```
echo "1"
echo "2"
echo "3"
```

What I would want is for each line to be executed in a new Powershell instance. So in the example above, 3 additional instances would be created and each of the 3 would execute one line from the text file. I'm able to launch instances, but I cannot get the instances to treat the lines in the file as commands.

```
$textFile=$args[0] #File with Powershell commands

foreach($cmdd in get-content $textFile){
    cmd /c start powershell -NoExit -command {param($cmdd) iex $cmdd} -ArgumentList $cmdd
}
```

Running this code opens the instances, prints a lot of information, and then immediately closes. It closes so quickly that I cannot see what the info is. However, since the text file is only composed of printing the numbers 1, 2, and 3, I don't think that it's working correctly. Is there also a way to keep the windows from closing after execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're launching additional instances of PowerShell from PowerShell, you won't need to call cmd.  Try using `Start-Process`:

```
$textFile=$args[0] #File with Powershell commands

foreach($cmdd in get-content $textFile){
    Start-Process -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList "-NoExit -Command $cmdd"
}
```

This will leave newly created instances open as you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

Switch from CMD /C to CMD /K to leave the command session open after the command finishes.

Comment: The newly created instances still close. I want to keep those open too.

Comment: If you want to launch instances outside of the current session, you'll need to use Start-Process.  But I don't think you can use a scriptblock for your command argument in that context.